# Passing parameter (that is result of another model function) to a model function

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

How can i pass a parameter (that is a returned value of another model function) to a function of a model class.

here's my model class functions

```
public function get_products_categories()
{
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT category 
                           FROM products');
return $query->result_array();
}   


public function get_products_names($category)
{
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT name 
                           FROM products
                           WHERE category=$category');
return $query->result_array();
}
```

and here's how I am doing in the controller class

```
$this->load->model('products_model');
    $data['products_categories'] = $this->products_model->get_products_categories();
    $data['products_names'] = $this->products_model->get_products_names();
```

Now what I want is to pass `$products_categories` to the function `$this->products_model->get_products_names();` but this is not possible `$products_categories` is not variable here in the controller class but in the view file, it can be used as a variable

Any Ideas ?

Comment: `$this->products_model->get_products_names($data['products_categories'])`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but $products_categories[category] is what i want to send because category is a name of column in my database

Comment: Since you're using `result_array`, `$data['products_categories']` will be an array (of arrays).  Try `$data['products_categories'][0]['category']` (that will be the 1st row).

Comment: but how would I know how many distinct records are there in `category` column ?

Comment: `$data['products_categories']` is just an array, so: `count($data['products_categories'])`.  Or from inside `get_products_categories`, you can do `$query->num_rows()`.

Comment: What I want to do is `echo` category and then `echo` all its products names and then another category and so on ... till all categories

Comment: You need to loop through `$data['products_categories']` then call `get_products_names` on each one.

Comment: you mean inside the view file ?

Comment: Or in the controller.  I'd suggest the controller.

Comment: then how am i going to print them in the view file ?

Comment: You save the value into the `$data` array, then send 'em to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do? For example, if you want to list all of your products in the categories, you can do this:

```
$data['products_categories'] = $this->products_model->get_products_categories();
$data['products_names'] = array();

foreach($data['products_categories'] as $product){
  $data['products_names'][$product['category']] = $this->products_model->get_products_names($product['category']);
}
```

Comment: but if I want this loop work to be done in view file ? how can I ?

Comment: @Saaram: You really shouldn't be calling model functions from the view.

Comment: foreach($products_names as $cat=>$products){
   foreach($products as $product){
  printf("<li>%s</li>", $product['name']);
   }
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
$this->load->model('main_model');
$data1 = $this->main_model->function1();
```

//if u wnt to pass data1 to fun2() then

```
$data2 = $this->main_model->function2($data1);
```

if the second fun is in another model try to load it and then give as:

```
$data2 = $this->another_model->function2($data1);
```

damn sure it wotrks.....